# testing a function from node jasmin

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I'm still fairly new to testing, and am trying to figure out how to test a function in jasmine, node. Up to now I've only tested methods on my object.

I have a node.js module which only exports two of my functions, but I need to be able to test the other functions without exporting them, as I don't want them to be public.

This is some example code, as the real code isn't important

```
function initialize(item){
    //do some initializing
    return item;
}

function update(x){
   if(!this.initialized){
      initialize(this);
   }
   this.value = x;
   return this;
}

module.exports.update = update;
```

How would I write a test for the initialize function, without using the update method? 
Is there a way to do this? Or does everything have to be a part of an object, and then I only export the parts that I need?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Test `initialize` independently from `update`?

Comment: sorry about that, yes, I want to test initialize independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, functions you don't export are not accessible from outside. Your tests that require your module only see the exports. So you can test the initialize function only through calling the update function. Since the module just initializes once you may clear the require cache before each test to require the module again with a fresh / uninitialized state. [Clearing the require cache](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache) is officially allowed / not a hack.